# Where can I stream and or possibly download Grander Musashi RV legally online?

Tags: resources

I remember watching this animation called Grander Musashi RV as a kid. The original version is in cantonese if I am not mistaken. Is there a site legally online preferably where I can watch this again (whether it be in subbed or dubbed) + download it legally online?

Thanks.

Comment: I will edit the question assuming legally of course and because you are a new user I will upvote. Please keep in mind that requesting illegal/copyrighted material is off-topic on this site. I haven't tried having a look on [Crunchyroll](http://crunchyroll.com/), but you could see if they stream it there if they have it.

Comment: Older anime tend to not have online streaming rights and are thu typically only available on discs, due to a variety of complicated ownership and licensing issues. *Grander Musashi* is no exception.

Comment: Thank you @アズーサ for changing it to legally :). I have no qualms about paying for this. Its just that i have searched for it so long and had to seek help somewhere

Comment: @Krazer - Yup thats what i figured. I found the cantonese versions. No hint of the english ones :(